# HTML Inline Block Container -> responsive to slider

Tags: html

I have written a little HTML Code which is displaying 3 Images in a row with a underneath Header. I want to make it responsive, so it will show the pictues on mobile as a slider, which is scrolling automatically (if possible) between the images. I tried a lot of things but I didn´t succeed, does someone have an idea how to make it responsive? If it is not possible with a slider, maybe then all 3 pictures on mobile as well in a row?

This is my code:

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<style>
   div.container {
   display:inline-block;
   padding: 30px;
   }
</style>
<div class="container">
   <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0431/9559/6957/files/recycle_-_Kopie_-_Kopie_400x.png?v=1596041138" height="200" width="150">
   <h2 class="SectionHeader__Heading Heading u-h1" data-theme-editor-setting="section.1595944684240.title/escape">Monatliches Abonnement</h2>
</div>
<div class="container">
   <img class="middle-img" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0431/9559/6957/files/euro_1_400x.png?v=1596041395" height="200" width="150">
   <h2 class="SectionHeader__Heading Heading u-h1" data-theme-editor-setting="section.1595944684240.title/escape">Kauf auf Rechnung</h2>
</div>
<div class="container">
   <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0431/9559/6957/files/lkw2_400x.png?v=1596041406" height="200" width="210">
   <h2 class="SectionHeader__Heading Heading u-h1" data-theme-editor-setting="section.1595944684240.title/escape">Lieferung vor Ihre Tür</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: In order to be responsive your images should not have fixed height and width attributes in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the attached code, it will surely solve your issue but if it doesn't let me know in the comments, I will try my best to assist you.

In the answer I have added `position: relative;` to make it adjust itself on screens with less resolution.

I have a suggestion for you that use **Viewport Units** like `vw` for **width** and `vh` for **height** instead of `px` or `%` because it will help you make your webpage/website responsive. For your better understanding I have added an example in *padding* by changing `padding: 30px;` to padding: `2.196vw;`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <style>
    div.container {
        display:inline-block;
        position: relative;
        padding: 2.196vw;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
   <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0431/9559/6957/files/recycle_-_Kopie_-_Kopie_400x.png?v=1596041138" height="200" width="150">
   <h2 class="SectionHeader__Heading Heading u-h1" data-theme-editor-setting="section.1595944684240.title/escape">Monatliches Abonnement</h2>
</div>
<div class="container">
   <img class="middle-img" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0431/9559/6957/files/euro_1_400x.png?v=1596041395" height="200" width="150">
   <h2 class="SectionHeader__Heading Heading u-h1" data-theme-editor-setting="section.1595944684240.title/escape">Kauf auf Rechnung</h2>
</div>
<div class="container">
   <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0431/9559/6957/files/lkw2_400x.png?v=1596041406" height="200" width="210">
   <h2 class="SectionHeader__Heading Heading u-h1" data-theme-editor-setting="section.1595944684240.title/escape">Lieferung vor Ihre Tür</h2>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a wrapper div with class "images-wrapper" outside the three containers

Modify your css as below

```
.images-wrapper {
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 30px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```